# How to deploy and run .ova file on the web server?

Tags: virtual-machine

How to deploy and run .ova file on the web server? Need to run an app (Galaxy bioinformatics software instance) which was developed inside a Virtual CentOS.

Answer (score 0):

You need to have some form of virtualization software installed that would be able to use those files. Various solutions support the format.

[This](https://www.perforce.com/perforce/doc.current/manuals/commons/OVA-INSTALL.html) could be used as a guide. Essentially:

- Install VirtualBox
- Start VirtualBox and select File -> Import Appliance
- Make sure the network settings etc. are correct for the VM
- Start VM